# Get selected items names from multiselect with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, meteor, multi-select, meteor-blaze, checkboxlist

How to get selected items names from multiselect with checkboxes? How do I save it as a record in Meteor js since it could be an array. I got this pretty multiselect checkbox from a site. How do I get the selected checked items / names from the dropdown?

```
<template name="AddSchoolLayout">
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="educationascope" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="dropdown-button noselect" id="educ_scope">
            <div class="dropdown-label" id="ed_scope">Educational Scope</div>
            <div class="dropdown-quantity">(<span class="quantity">Any</span>)</div>
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-list" id="scope_edu" style="display: none; width: 100%;">
            <input type="search" id="search_edu" placeholder="Search/Select Educational Scope" class="dropdown-search form-control" style="width: 100%;" />
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#educationascope')
    .on('click', '#educ_scope', function() {
        $('#scope_edu').toggle();
    })
    .on('input', '#search_edu', function() {
        var target = $(this);
        var search = target.val().toLowerCase();

        if (!search) {
            $('li').show();
            return false;
        }

        $('li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var match = text.indexOf(search) > -1;
            $(this).toggle(match);
        });
    })
    .on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var numChecked = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        $('.quantity').text(numChecked || 'Any');
    });

// JSON of School curriculum for demo purposes

    var eduscope = [
        { name: 'Scotish', abbreviation: 'SC'},
        { name: 'Nigerian', abbreviation: 'NG'},
        { name: 'Britsh', abbreviation: 'BR'},
        { name: 'American', abbreviation: 'AM'},
        { name: 'Canadian', abbreviation: 'CA'},
        { name: 'Mexican', abbreviation: 'WY' }
    ];

    // <li> template
    var schoolTemplate = _.template(
        '<li>' +
            '<input name="<%= abbreviation %>" type="checkbox">' +
            '<label for="<%= abbreviation %>"><%= capName %></label>' +
        '</li>'
    );

    // Populate list with states
    lodash.each(eduscope, function(s) {
        s.capName = lodash.startCase(s.name.toLowerCase());
        $('ul').append(schoolTemplate(s));
    });
    </script>
    </template>
```

This is the event class

```
Template.AddSchoolLayout.events({
    'submit .addnewschool': function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var selectedvalues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
            return $(el).val();
        }).get();

        Meteor.call('SchoolRegister', selectedvalues,
                function (error, response) {
                    if (error) {
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        FlowRouter.redirect('/contact');
                    }
                });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your problem to the minimal question and build back up; how to get all the selected values from a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) [*HTMLSelectElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)

```js
var select = document.querySelector('.foo');

select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var values = Array.prototype.map.call(
        e.currentTarget.selectedOptions,
        function (option) {
            return option.value;
        }
    );
    console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<select multiple class="foo">
    <option value="bar">A</option>
    <option value="baz">B</option>
</select>
```

In blaze, you would add the listener using the template's events rather than vanilla here

---

If `selectedOptions` does not meet all your browser compatibility requirements, you would need an extra step to filter the select's options for only the selected ones.